# how can we start or stop a application which is deployed on weblogic

Tags: webserver, web-application

I want to stop a application which is deployed on weblogic temporarily, that means I should be able to start the application immediately without deploying on weblogic.

Answer (score 0):

We can achieve this by using weblogic mbeans. Please find below code for your reference.

**appRuntime.stop();**

**appRuntime.start();**

```
    @Override
public void stop(String deploymentName)
{
    System.out.println("*** Stopping webapp...");

    // The DeploymentManagerMBean is used for the initial deployment of an application.
    // After the initial deployment, the AppDeploymentRuntimeMBean is used for stop, start,
    // redeploy, and undeploy of an application.

    AppDeploymentRuntimeMBean appRuntime = deploymentManager.lookupAppDeploymentRuntime(deploymentName);

    DeploymentProgressObjectMBean progressObj = appRuntime.stop();
    printCompletionStatus(progressObj);
}

@Override
public void start(String deploymentName)
{
    System.out.println("*** Starting webapp...");

    // The DeploymentManagerMBean is used for the initial deployment of an application.
    // After the initial deployment, the AppDeploymentRuntimeMBean is used for stop, start,
    // redeploy, and undeploy of an application.

    AppDeploymentRuntimeMBean appRuntime = deploymentManager.lookupAppDeploymentRuntime(deploymentName);

    DeploymentProgressObjectMBean progressObj = appRuntime.start();
    printCompletionStatus(progressObj);
}
```

we need to pass the deployment name as perameter while accessing appRuntime